# `UIAlertController` is not triggered in NSNotification response

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, uialertcontroller, nsnotifications, presentviewcontroller

This is my `AlertView` code :

```
- (void)initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title withMessage:(NSString *)msg withYesButtonTitle:(NSString *)yesButtonTitle withYesButtonAction:(id)yesButtonAction
{
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                 message:msg
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* yesBtn = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:yesButtonTitle
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                 if (self.activityIndicator.animating) {
                                     [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                 }

                                 if ([title isEqualToString:@"Wrong Password!"]) {
                                     self.editTextField.text = @"";
                                     [self.editTextField becomeFirstResponder];
                                 }
                             }];

    [alert addAction:yesBtn];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am trying to fire this alert in my `NSNotificatoin Response` method. My `Notification Response` code :

```
- (void)receiveSMSVerificationResponse:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    SMSVerificationDigitClassModel *smsVerificationDigitClassModel = [[SMSVerificationDigitClassModel alloc] init];
    smsVerificationDigitClassModel = [notification object];

    if (smsVerificationDigitClassModel.viewControllerName == ViewControllerNameProfileInfoEditViewController) {

        if ([self alreadyRegisteredPhoneNumber:smsVerificationDigitClassModel.phoneNumber] == YES) {
            NSLog(@"jogajog");
            [self initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Already Registered!" withMessage:kAlreadyRegisteredPhoneNumberMSGForChangePhoneNumber withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];

        } else {
            if ([AdditionalClasses internetConnectionCheck] == YES) {
                self.userModelClass.phone_number = smsVerificationDigitClassModel.phoneNumber;
                [self updateUserModel:self.userModelClass];
            } else {
                [self noInternetConnectionAlert];
            }
        }
        //Check if that phone number is already used
        // udate phone numner in server
        // update phone number in core data
        //[self goToSignUpViewControllerWithPhoneNumber:smsVerificationDigitClassModel.phoneNumber];
    }
}
```

I check it from break point, this line `[self initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Already Registered!" withMessage:kAlreadyRegisteredPhoneNumberMSGForChangePhoneNumber withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];` is actually calling, but the alert view is not popping up. It says:

**"Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"**

I have tried to add notification observer methods :

```
- (void)addNotificationObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveUserModelResponse:) name:@"sendUpdateRequestToServerForPhoneNumberWithUserModel" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveSMSVerificationResponse:) name:@"SMSVerificationForPhoneNumber" object:nil];
}
```

In `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` & in `viewWillAppear` and `removeObserver` in `dealloc`,

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"sendUpdateRequestToServerForPhoneNumberWithUserModel" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"SMSVerificationForPhoneNumber" object:nil];
}
```

but it is not showing at all. So, how do I change my `window hierarchy!` in this `viewController`. If you understand, please reply back. A lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle method inside a main queue dispatch queue block.

**All UI operation should be on main threat.**

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self initializeAlertControllerForOneButtonWithTitle:@"Already Registered!" withMessage:kAlreadyRegisteredPhoneNumberMSGForChangePhoneNumber withYesButtonTitle:@"Ok" withYesButtonAction:nil];
 });
```